# Spreadsheet aggregation/manipulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet structured like

```
2005    Alameda     total HS graduates   1234
2005    Alameda     UC enrollees         112 
2006    Alameda     total HS graduates   892
2006    Alameda     UC enrollees         84
...
2009    Yolo        total HS graduates   1300
2009    Yolo        UC enrollees         93
```

and so on for every CA county for several years.

I want to generate a spreadsheet like this:

```
  county    2005     2006   ...
  Alameda   11.1%     9%
  Alpine       7%     8% 
  ... 
  Yolo       5.5%     4%
```

i.e. I want to project the years from rows to columns and have a row for each county, then divide the number of graduates (the data from each odd-numbered row in the original sheet) by the number of UC enrollees (even-row data) for each year, and insert it in the appropriate cell.

This would be easy enough for me to do in Java, but I want to get a feel for what's possible just using excel/Google sheets alone - how might I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the counties are sorted, and they start in cell B2, enter `=B2` in cell F2, and enter the following in F3:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&COUNTIF(B3:B$9999,"<="&F2)+ROW())
```

You can change `9999` based on the number of records, but it's fine as-is.

Copy F3 down as many rows as are needed:

[image]

You can then calculate percentages using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=IFERROR(
  SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$100=G$1)*
             ($B$2:$B$100=$F2)*
             ($C$2:$C$100="UC enrollees")*
             $D$2:$D$100
             )
  /
  SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$100=G$1)*
             ($B$2:$B$100=$F2)*
             ($C$2:$C$100="total HS graduates")*
             $D$2:$D$100
  ),
  "")
```

[image]

The first `SUMPRODUCT` totals UC enrollees that match the year and county.  The second `SUMPRODUCT` does the same for HS graduates.  The results are divided, and `IFERROR` handles divide-by-zero errors for missing data.

Since your example shows percentages, I assume you want to divide UC enrollees by HS graduates, and not the other way around.  Either way, I don't get the same totals as you, so let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: looks great - thanks. I'll try it out and accept when I get home!

Comment: How about doing the same for the column headers (years)? Set G1 to =small($A:$A,1), then H1 to =SMALL($A:$A,COUNTIF($A:$A,"<="&G1)+1) ?

Comment: Thanks! Yours shows the power of an array-formula type approach, hopefully the two solutions are complementary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pivot table way of doing it for comparison.

They are many ways of doing this but I've added column headers and chosen to use this formula to put percentages in even rows of column E and zeroes in odd rows in sheet 1:-

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),D3/D2*100,0)
```

[image]

Then I've inserted a pivot table in sheet 2 referring to my data in sheet 1 and set up the fields as shown and it's pretty automatic:-

[image]

Comment: Note to self - it was  unnecessary to multiply by 100 in my percentage calculation: if you choose a percentage format, it does it for you.